# PHP - 2 associative arrays in a table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a SELECT STATEMENT which returns 3 values: Id, titel, erscheinungsdatum.
I'm fetching the values in 2 Arrays called $filme and $datum.

That all works pretty fine, but I want the **two** associative arrays in **one** table as ouput.

```
$query->bind_result($id, $titel, $date);
$query->execute();

while($query->fetch()) {

    $filme[$id] = $titel;
    $datum[$id] = $date;
}
if(!empty($filme) && !empty($datum)) {

    echo "

    <table border='3'>
    <th>Filmtitel</th>
    <th>ErscheinungsDatum</th>
    ";


    foreach($filme as $key => $value) {

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>$value</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    foreach($datum as $key => $value) {

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>$value</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "

    </table>
    ";
}
```

I've tried double foreach loops, merge_function, among others...

Comment: Can you show us some sample input (your two arrays)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a twodimensional array, constructed like this:

```
while($query->fetch()) {
    // I suppose some processing is done here...
    $filme[$id]['titel'] = $titel;
    $filme[$id]['date'] = $date;
}
```

which can be output like this:

```
foreach($filme as $key => $value) {
    echo "<tr>";
    printf("<td>%s</td><td>%s</td>",$value['titel'],$value['date']);
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

If there's no postprocessing / intermediate processing to be done, @danmullen's suggestion should also work.

Comment: Hey. Its working pretty fine now. With the twodimensional array I can point on everything I want. Thank you very much! ;)

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're trying to do is have both values (from `$datum` and `$filme`) in one row.

So at the minute, you're outputting each value into a column in a separate row.

You need to output values from both arrays in one table row to achieve your desired output.

```
foreach($filme as $key => $value) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$value</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $datum[$key] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

**Edit:** as a side note, you need to wrap your `<th></th>` tags in `<thead><tr></tr></thead>`

Comment: Maybe not, but this was my understanding of the question. Judging by the values in the table headings, this is the output he is looking for.

Comment: Assuming 3 films, the output will be `<tr><td>title1</td><td>date1</td></tr><tr><td>title2</td><td>date2</td></tr><tr><td>title3</td><td>date3</td></tr>` which is what I would expect judging from the `<thead>`

Comment: I made a mistake myself which I didn't pick up on. Please see the edit.

Comment: much better now and indeed a valid solution, +1  but please remove the reference to first and second loops....

Comment: +1, not only is this now a valid solution, it doesn't require changing how the data is stored (in the case where the two separate arrays is a requirement).

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to have the results in two associative arrays, or is the final table all you need?

If you don't need the arrays, just build the table up inside the `while($query->fetch())`

Comment: This works also. Thank you for your help! Sometimes I think to complex for such easy things. :X